# Post and featured image have the same name, why is the attachment (image) is showing and not the post?

Tags: images, media

How do I get the actual POST to display - and not the thumbnail of the image?

I have tried to redirect the attachment to the parent post, but that gets caught in a redirect loop.

For an example - right now, until this is fixed, go here: http://www.festivalsinpa.com/city/ford-city/ - and you will see one festival listed. If you click the listing, it defaults to the thumbnail and not the post.

--Thanks

Comment: this is a known issue and a result of having permalinks set to `/%postname%/`, [see this trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24612).

Comment: Thank you Milo - I searched for quite a while trying to determine what I had to do.